# testing with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

i've developed before_filter - http://gist.github.com/138659 and in
tests like

```
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:articles)
  end
```

i see

> ```
> test_should_get_index(ArticlesControllerTest):
> NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
> You might have expected an instance of Array.
> The error occurred while evaluating nil.split
>     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in
> ```
>
> `set_locale'
>           /test/functional/articles_controller_test.rb:5:in`
>   test_should_get_index'

When i've added

```
setup do
@request.headers['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en"
end
```

nothing changed :( Could you tell me plz - whats wrong?

Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue with

```
@request.env['HOST'] = "somesite.com"
@request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en"
```